# Unordered list in a table cell with Asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am trying to have a (simple) unordered list in a table cell in an Asciidoc document.  I use `asciidoctor`.

I tried the following:

```
|===
| One | Two

| Foo
|
- Bar
- Baz
|===
```

But this results in the last cell having simply the text `- Bar - Baz` as a simple string, no list formatting.  I would like it to be formatted as a list, on two lines, with a bullet on each line.  Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default style of a table cell accepts only inline markup. To insert block elements you could change the cell style to "AsciiDoc". See [this document](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/tables/format-cell-content/) for details.

For example:

```
|===
| One | Two

| Foo
a|
- Bar
- Baz
|===
```

*Word of caution: The contents of the cell is treated as a separate AsciiDoc document, so certain markup (such as footnotes) behave badly as they no longer belong to the main document.*

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed what I was looking for!  Now these cells come with an extra blank space at the bottom (roughly the height of a text line,) but at least they have proper lists now :-)